# Sentry SDK Java is not working on aws lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, sentry

I am trying to use sentry in java based aws lambda. I am trying to used sentry `v3.1.1` in a simple lambda which captures exception as below. The problem is

- it `works fine when run locally using main method`, and event appears on sentry issues ui
- but it `doesn't work when invoked in as aws lambda` and event never appears on sentry ui.

#### SentryLambda.java

```java
package playground.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import io.sentry.Sentry;

public class SentryLambda implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

  @Override
  public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
    Sentry.init();
    Sentry.captureException(new Exception("Test Sentry"));
    return "Returned "  + input;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SentryLambda sentryLambda = new SentryLambda();
    sentryLambda.handleRequest("Requested String", null);
  }

}
```

#### pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>playground.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-sentry</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
      <artifactId>sentry</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}-jar-with-dependencies</finalName>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="com.github.edwgiz.maven_shade_plugin.log4j2_cache_transformer.PluginsCacheFileTransformer">
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.edwgiz</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin.log4j2-cachefile-transformer</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

#### sentry.properties

```
dsn=...removed intentionally...
environment=development
release=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
stacktrace.app.packages=playground.demo
```

#### samp-template.tml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Sentry Lambda

Resources:
  SentryLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: sentryLambda
      Handler: playground.demo.SentryLambda
      Runtime: java8
      CodeUri: target/aws-lambda-sentry-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 15
      AutoPublishAlias: DEFAULT
      Role: ... a role with AWSLambdaFullAccess policy ...
```

I also tried creating aws lambda with vpc config and internet access but did not succeed
Can anyone please guide me why it's not working and how can I make it work?

**P.S.**
Before all this, I tried working with [sentry-log4j2](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/log4j2/) and [sentry-logback](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/logback/), and eventually reached to simple [sentry-java](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/). They all work locally but fail on aws lambda

---

[Update: Nov 02, 2020]

As @Manoel suggested to set debug flag, here's the updated code and logs.

#### SentryLambda.java

```
    ...
    Sentry.init(options -> {
      options.setDebug(true);
      options.setDsn("...");
      options.setEnvironment("development");
      options.setRelease("0.0.1-SNAPSHOT");
    });
    ...
```

#### Logs

```
/aws/lambda/sentryLambda 2020/11/02/[$LATEST]da849aebc90744409bbc11f98ac49c2a START RequestId: b3f6c0f5-3a89-4f62-8994-7d4b198351e5 Version: $LATEST
/aws/lambda/sentryLambda 2020/11/02/[$LATEST]da849aebc90744409bbc11f98ac49c2a INFO: Initializing SDK with DSN: '...'
/aws/lambda/sentryLambda 2020/11/02/[$LATEST]da849aebc90744409bbc11f98ac49c2a INFO: No outbox dir path is defined in options.
/aws/lambda/sentryLambda 2020/11/02/[$LATEST]da849aebc90744409bbc11f98ac49c2a INFO: GlobalHubMode: 'false'
/aws/lambda/sentryLambda 2020/11/02/[$LATEST]da849aebc90744409bbc11f98ac49c2a DEBUG: UncaughtExceptionHandlerIntegration enabled: true
/aws/lambda/sentryLambda 2020/11/02/[$LATEST]da849aebc90744409bbc11f98ac49c2a DEBUG: UncaughtExceptionHandlerIntegration installed.
/aws/lambda/sentryLambda 2020/11/02/[$LATEST]da849aebc90744409bbc11f98ac49c2a DEBUG: Capturing event: ff1def349ab34a5eb151d52e7dd72425
/aws/lambda/sentryLambda 2020/11/02/[$LATEST]da849aebc90744409bbc11f98ac49c2a INFO: Session is null on scope.withSession
/aws/lambda/sentryLambda 2020/11/02/[$LATEST]da849aebc90744409bbc11f98ac49c2a END RequestId: b3f6c0f5-3a89-4f62-8994-7d4b198351e5
```

Comment: There is indeed an problem with sending events from AWS Lambda. I created an issue: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/1023

Answer (score 1):

could you enable the `debug` mode and copy-paste the logs?

```
Sentry.init(options -> {
  options.setDebug(true);
});
```